# Kendo UI DropDownList dataSource from external url not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, jsonp

Original code http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/template.html

Json file like the original, only in a different location.
Project: [http://jsfiddle.net/rbogdanowicz/RRdQ4/2/](http://bit.ly/17wKf69)

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in between the responses, your one is wrappeped in callback keyword :

```
callback([{"CustomerID":"ALFKI","ContactName":"Maria Anders","CompanyName":"Alfreds Futterkiste"},{"CustomerID":"ANATR","ContactName":"Ana Trujillo","CompanyName":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados"}]);
```

Kendo one is not.
Solution is to set jsonpCallback parametr (fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/2JTsT/):

```
transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonpCallback: "callback",
                    url: "http://www1.com.br/Customers",
                }
            }
```

Comment: Many thanks Bobby_D_!
Works fine...
Thank u very very much... =)